# How to get only the first instance of a substring from a string?

Tags: python, string

I am using some code to check a text file for some information, `extractedInfo`, in between my search criteria `searchKey` and `searchEndKey`:

```
data1 = mytextfile
searchKey = "https://cars/"
searchEndKey = "/ford/" 
extractedInfo = data1[data1.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey):data1.find(searchEndKey,data1.find(searchKey)+len(searchKey)+1)]
```

Which works as expected if there is only one instance of the search keys, but if there are multiple instances of it then it grabs all the info starting from the start of the first `searchKey` all the way to the end of the last `searchEndKey`.

For example if the text file has in it:

> blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah

My returned value is `123456`.

But if the text file has in it:

> blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah
>   https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah
>   https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah

My returned value is:
`123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456`

So is there a way I can tell python to stop after it has finished getting the info between the first search keys it has already found?

Comment: It works for me, if mytextfile is a string. Is 'mytextfile' is a file name or a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple text split extraction work for you?

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read() # read your file into a string

searchKey = "https://cars/"
searchEndKey = "/ford/"

extracted = data.split(searchKey)[1].split(searchEndKey)[0]
```

This will only get the first occurrence. Granted, it is not too efficient for very long strings.

Input:

```
blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah
```

output:

```
123456
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with regex using `re.search()`. Something like:

```
import re

s = 'blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah blah blah https://cars/123456/ford/ blah blah'

patt = re.compile(r'https:\/\/cars\/([^\/]*)\/ford\/')
result = patt.search(s)

print(result.group(1))
# OUTPUT
# 123456
```